# converting a chunk of repeated php into a function?

Tags: php, function, dry

I have little programming experience so the jump from basic php to using  classes, functions etc is a little daunting.

I'm building a little php script that works out what "theme" a user has selected via a form and from that selection, it loads some specific files. I've built a working script, but there's so much repetition in it, it's a joke.

```
// Add our theme names to variables
$theme1 = "theme1";
$theme2 = "theme2";
$theme3 = "theme3";

// Test to see what Theme the user chose.
// Theme 1
if ($themeChoice==$theme1) 
{
    // Load the theme
    $homepage = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme1.'/index.html');
    $mobile_js_main = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme1.'/js/main.js');
    $mobile_js_jquery = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme1.'/js/jquery.js');
    $mobile_css_easy = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme1.'/css/easy.css'); 
    $mobile_images_bg = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme1.'/images/bg.png');   
    $mobile_images_footer = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme1.'/images/footer.png');   
    $mobile_images_nav = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme1.'/images/nav.png'); 

    if ($AddPortfolioPage != '')
    {
        $portfolioPage = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme1.'/portfolio.html');
    }

    if ($AddContactPage != '')
    {
        $ContactPage = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme1.'/contact.html');
    }

    if ($AddBlankPage != '')
    {
        $blankPage = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme1.'/blank.html');
    }           
}
```

This is then repeated for each theme...which is obviously not an ideal method of doing this. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all of your themes into an array and loop to find the chosen one.

```
$themes = array( "theme1", "theme2", "theme3");

foreach( $themes as $theme)
{
    if( $themeChoice == $theme)
    {
        $homepage = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme.'/index.html');
        $mobile_js_main = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme.'/js/main.js');
        $mobile_js_jquery = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme.'/js/jquery.js');
        $mobile_css_easy = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme.'/css/easy.css'); 
        $mobile_images_bg = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme.'/images/bg.png');   
        $mobile_images_footer = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme.'/images/footer.png');   
        $mobile_images_nav = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme.'/images/nav.png'); 

        if ($AddPortfolioPage != '')
        {
            $portfolioPage = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme.'/portfolio.html');
        }

       if ($AddContactPage != '')
        {
            $ContactPage = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme.'/contact.html');
        }

        if ($AddBlankPage != '')
        {
            $blankPage = file_get_contents('../themes/'.$theme.'/blank.html');
        }           

        break; // Break will exit the loop once the choice is found
    }
}
```

Comment: The for loop is completely useless... he can just check if the theme is in the array using `in_array()`

Comment: @shesek - Checking for existence isn't the point of his code sample.

Comment: @shesek - No it isn't - it sets all of the variables to their correct values.